# How to detect an escape in a string

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string message = "Hello\r\"world\"";

int main() {
    if (message[5] == '\\') {
        switch (message[6]) {
            case 'r':
                std::cout << "\\r escape..." << std::endl;
            break;
            case '"':
                std::cout << "\" escape..." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know that logically it's right, but if you understood what I'm trying to do, you will notice that I want to know if there's a escape on the string. If the character is a escape, do what you see above (the switch).

Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: It's "escape", not "scape", and looking for backslashes doesn't make sense because *there are no backslashes in the string*.  There are backslashes in the *code* that *creates* the string, but the effect of that code (the string constant) is to create a string in memory without them.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as these characters are escaped by the compiler, and thus not known at runtime.

Comment: @Pointy - It was a mistake,  I will edit.

Comment: You can check, for example, if a character is considered a *control character* for a certain charset/locale: [`iscntrl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/iscntrl)

Comment: @MikeChristensen `'\r'`? Besides that: ASCII clearly defines these chars.

Comment: @Paranaix - See the code and you will understand.

Comment: "I know that logically it's right" No it's not

Comment: @SH.0x90: I assure you, Paranaix is correct and your code is not.

Comment: @MooingDuck - "I know that logical it's right, to don't work, and return the character instead of the escape code" - And the code is just to illustrate what I want. Look what I wrote on the end: "but if you understood what I'm trying to do, you will notice that I want to know if there's a escape on the string.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.  At runtime, you'll have the following bytes in the string:

1. <kbd>H</kbd>
2. <kbd>e</kbd>
3. <kbd>l</kbd>
4. <kbd>l</kbd>
5. <kbd>o</kbd>
6. <kbd>CR</kbd> (ASCII Character 13)
7. <kbd>"</kbd> (ASCII Character 34)
8. <kbd>w</kbd>
9. <kbd>o</kbd>
10. <kbd>r</kbd>
11. <kbd>l</kbd>
12. <kbd>d</kbd>
13. <kbd>"</kbd> (ASCII Character 34)

The fact that this string constant *happened* to be created through escape sequences is completely irrellevent, as this is just compiler shorthand to create the above bytes.  No where in memory will the backslash exist, thus there's no way at *runtime* to detect these escape sequences.

You could, of course, look to see if byte 6 was 13, or byte 7 was 34.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike posted, string escapes are a way to *type* non-printable characters into a string in a programming language.  The escapes themselves are not actually in the string with a `\`.  The character represented by `'\n'` is what is in the string.  Ergo, did you want something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::string message = "Hello\r\"world\"";

int main() {
    switch (message[5]) {
        case '\\': std::cout << "\\\\ escape...\n"; break;
        case '\"': std::cout << "\\\" escape...\n"; break;
        case '\'': std::cout << "\\\' escape...\n"; break;
        case '\?': std::cout << "\\? escape...\n"; break;
        case '\a': std::cout << "\\a escape...\n"; break;
        case '\b': std::cout << "\\b escape...\n"; break;
        case '\f': std::cout << "\\f escape...\n"; break;
        case '\n': std::cout << "\\n escape...\n"; break;
        case '\r': std::cout << "\\r escape...\n"; break;
        case '\t': std::cout << "\\t escape...\n"; break;
        case '\v': std::cout << "\\v escape...\n"; break;
        case '\0': std::cout << "\\0 escape...\n"; break;
        default:
            if (isprint(message[5]))
                std::cout << message[5] << " is not an escape...\n";
            else {
                std::cout << "\\x";
                std::cout << std::hex << ((unsigned char)message[5]);
                std::cout << " escape...\n" << std::dec;
            }
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are also other escapes that have value parameters, and are not detectable in any manner, because they're not unique.

```
These are all identical after compilation
"\0a" //raw ASCII
"\n0\n141" //octal - ASCII
"\x0\x61" //hexidecimal - ASCII
"\u0061" //codepoint - UTF16
```

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks, I'm shocked that I overlooked that if statement